# How to call linux/c++ function with Mono/C# program?

Tags: c#, c++, linux, mono

I googled a lot but couldn't find a solution to my very specific problem, at least it seems to be very specific.
I have the following situation:

Embedded Linux (Debian) on a ARM-Board. I have "old" C++ Applications running, which send and receive data via CAN Bus and the SocketCAN API.

But recently i worked on a few projects in C# and really liked the .NET Framework, which is why i installed Mono on my Embedded System.
Running pure C# Applications is no problem.

But now i want to access the CAN Bus via Mono/C# Applications which seems to be a problem because there is no api as socketcan. Thats why i have the idea to call the c++ function which creates and handles the underlying Socket operations, while my C# program processes the data.

I found things like invoking c++ functions, or compiling the c++ function/classes as DLLs and them calling them in C#. Problem is, that i haven't found a solution how to compile my SocketCAN/C++ Program in to a DLL, because my Visual Studio Compiler on my Host Windows Machine obviously can't know the linux kernel can utilities.

So does someone have an idea how i can solve this problem? i can see that there are maybe more solutions to this, but i can't figure out one.

Comment: You don't necessary need to compile it as dll. You can as well invoke functions from (for example) .so files, with regular pinvoke.

Comment: Note that, in the end, .so is for Linux what .dll is for Windows: they are dynamic libraries that programs can use.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote a lib.so file which contains my functions, but when i try to call them with my c# program i get System.EntryPointNotFoundException. I guess this is because i declared my functions with [code] extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)[/code], which somehow seems to be for windows. Whats the right declaration?

Comment: @rele92 I've edited my answer below

Answer (score 1):

What do your libraries look like? Can you create `.so` from them? If yes, then everything's fine. As far as I know MONO can handle interop on the appropriate level.

[MONO Interop](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/)

Please note that you should care about calling conventions ([link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx), [link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx)) and probably use the full form:

```
[DllImport("mylib.so", EntryPoint = "my_func1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention::Cdecl,  CharSet = CharSet::Ansi)]
```

For your `extern "C"` I guess that `Cdecl` would be appropriate (and if not, check the others ^-^)

From the link to MONO documentation above:

> Calling convention can be specified in C code by using the `__stdcall` and `__cdecl` compiler intrinsics under Microsoft Visual C++, and by using the `__attribute__((stdcall))` and `__attribute__((cdecl))` compiler intrinsics under GCC.

Disclaimer: I don't use MONO (nor do I know what C/C++ compiler you use) so you'll need to check it.